# Combining Range and Histogram Filter in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider an event log stored in ElasticSearch. Events look like this

```
{
  "timestamp": "2013-04-04T15:38:17Z",
  "color": "red"
}

{
  "timestamp": "2013-04-04T17:51:21Z",
  "color": "green"
}
```

I want to draw frequency timelines per color. I know that I can get the timelines with two queries like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "color": "red"
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "facets": {
    "freq": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "interval": "day",
        "field": "timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second query would `"match": { "color": "green" }`.

Can I combine these queries into one, that gives my either

- count(color) / day / bucket
- or one facet per color, containing the histogram for that color?

For two colors separate queries could work just fine, but as you might suspect this is a contrieved example. I am really dealing with more than ten colors and at this point a single query would be really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine facets for different colors into the same request using [facet_filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/):

```
{
    "facets": {
        "freq_red": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "interval": "day",
                "field": "timestamp"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                "term": {
                    "color": "red"
                }
            }
        },
        "freq_green": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "interval": "day",
                "field": "timestamp"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                "term": {
                    "color": "green"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that in the docs. Is there a way run one facet for each color without knowing (or looking up) what colors there are?

Comment: @Peter: Sure TermsFacet allows you to do faceting per term, without knowing the terms beforehand. Here a term would be a color. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet/

Comment: Yes, terms facet will return you list of terms without histograms that can be later used to execute the multiple histogram facets query described above. But I cannot think of a way to execute both of them in a single query at the moment.